# Why can't I put a load between hot and the ground line?

Tags: grounding, neutral

Normally the load goes between hot and neutral line.

Since neutral is grounded why can't I put a load between hot and the ground line?

Comment: That does not answer my question. Since neutral is grounded there is a connection between grounded and grounding wire. Since this connection exists why can't I put a load between grounded wire and hot wire. Please leave alone safety. This is a purely theoretical question.

Answer (score 8):

Because the grounding system is a safety system, and is designed to only carry current during a fault.  If you use a grounding conductor as a grounded (neutral) conductor, you'll have current flowing on water pipes, faucets, appliance frames, metal electrical enclosures, and anything else that's grounded.

Doing this could lead to property damage, injury, and/or death.

Comment: Translated:  "you CAN.  But you'll kill someone."

Comment: Tester101 and Bob are right.  Electrically, it would work (in fact, if you looked inside the breaker panel [but don't, please!], you'd see all the neutrals and grounds tied together), but would create an extremely dangerous situation.

Comment: You would also trip any GFCI connected on that circuit.